# State not updating when update in same function in Redux

Tags: android, reactjs, redux, state

I am creating a task management application (in React, Redux)  which has  a Grid of  tasks  .The row of grid has a task name , task description and status (active / pending) and a save button to save the changes in database .The user can edit the task  and save . There is also a mark Active Button which will change the status of task to active (also save the same in database).
The mark active code is something like this

```
markActive(taskId){
this.props.markActive(taskId);/*update the state*/
this.props.saveData();/*send the updated state to database*/
```

}

My problem is when I save the data,the status of the task is not getting change in Database.
But this works

```
markActive(taskId){
this.props.markActive(taskId);
setTimeout(
    ()=>{this.props.saveData();}
    ,0
)
```

}

The problem is that `this.props.markActive(taskId)` is doing his work perfectly but the updated state has not reached to my component yet , when I use timeout the state get updated .
Is it a good practice to use timeout or is there any better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating state in React is an asynchronous operation, so you have no guarantees that when you call `this.props.saveData()`, your component already re-rendered with the new state.

`setTimeout` works because it's a way of telling the JS engine to wait for the next tick, so it suffices the purpose, but it's a bad practise to couple side effects with your components logic.

A better way of handling this async flow is to use redux middleware, such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), to isolate those side effects in a different part of your application.

With redux-thunk for instance, the action creator returns a **function** instead of an object and that function will get executed by the Redux Thunk middleware. This function doesn’t need to be pure; it is thus allowed to have side effects, including DB calls. Redux Thunk offers you a way to read the current state of the Redux store. In addition to dispatch, it also passes getState as the second argument to the function you return from your thunk action creator.

So you could have an action creator such as:

```
function markActiveDbSync(taskId) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(markTaskAsActive(taskId));
        // redux store state updated properly, now you are good to go to sync with your DB
        saveDataToDb(getState());
     }
}
```

For further reference, I recommend you to check the concept of [Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) within Redux as well.